# accessing array from datatable column in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, datatable

I have a datatable like below which contains several columns. One of the datatable column has value as json array ( Contacts ). I want to access `name` property from the column.

```
Name     ID    Contacts 
User1    1     [{ "id": 1, "name": "User3", } }]]
```

Comment: Database columns don't contain arrays. Most likely you mean that `Contacts` contains a JSON string. Use JSON.NET or another JSON serializer to read the contents.

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL Server 2016+ and PostgreSQL have JSON funcions which means you could just extract the contact names instead of the entire object. Otherwise you'll have to deserialize the JSON string and read the `name` value

Comment: Its a datatable with json(converted to string).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos its not true. Postgresql has arrays but only simple one dimensional.

Comment: @daremachine what isn't true? That Postgres supports JSON? That this data looks like JSON? Do we really need to start a discussion about SQL, the language vs the customizations introduced by each vendor and how easy or hard it is to index and query multivalue fields even when they are available? Thus making multivalue columns problematic even when they are available?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos @daremachine This question has (as far as I can tell) nothing to do with a Database. OP is using a `Datatable` UI Control

Comment: @MindSwipe Datatable isn't a UI control. It's a class used for *data access*. It's seldom used outside that scenario. Extracting the `name` attribute using the database's functions can be *easier* or *faster* than doing so in the client

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my mistake, I'm only somewhat familiar with the Datatable in JSF where it is used to dynamically render Html tables

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "JSON serializer to read the contents" - Thats the question actually. can you provide a sample code if possible?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I gave like you but my comment was to your first sentence. Others all right and I agree with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table contains a JSON string, not an array. To get the field's contents one would have to deserialize it using [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) and read its contents, eg :

```
var contactValue=(string)table.Rows[0]["Contacts"];            
var contacts=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(contactValue);
Console.WriteLine("{0}",contacts[0].name);
```

[JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm) can deserialize a JSON string into a concrete type or a dynamic object. In this example the contents are deserialized into a dynamic object that contains an array. `contacts[0].name` will return the name attribute of the first element.

It's better to create a concrete type instead of using dynamic in this case:

```
class Contact 
{
        public int id {get;set;}
        public string name{get;set;}
}
```

This allows the use of LINQ to retrieve specific attributes, eg :

```
var  contacts=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contact[]>(contactValue);

//Iterate over the results
foreach(var contact in contacts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(contact.name);
}
//Or use LINQ
var names=contacts.Select(it=>it.name).ToList();
```

**Using JSONPath**

Another option could be to use [JSONPath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) to extract specific values without parsing the entire string.

Instead of deserializing the string, it's parsed with `JArray.Parse` or `JObject.Parse`. After that, `SelectTokens` is used to retrieve the values that match a query path:

```
var array=JArray.Parse(contactValue);
var tokens=array.SelectTokens("$..name");
foreach(var token in tokens)
{
    Console.WriteLine(token);
}
//Concatenate all names into a string
string allNames=String.Join(",",tokens);
```

`$..name` means

> For any element, return any attribute named `name` no matter where it is in the hierarchy (`..`)